# Best way to encrypt password in a WP Plugin page

Tags: php, wordpress, password-encryption

My problem is that I want to store a password into my custom plugin settings, but I don't know how to encrypt it before it is stored in the database. I know how to use password_hash, but not in this scenario.

I have build the password form in my plugin options page. I registered my plugin options and builded the form to store the password:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'MY_register_settings');
function MY_register_settings() {
  register_setting( 'MY_settings', 'MY_settings' );
}

<form method="post" action="options.php">
  <?php settings_fields( 'MY_settings' ); ?>
  <?php do_settings_sections( 'MY_settings_page' ); ?>
  <input id="password" type="password" name="MY_settings[password]">
  <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

How do I target my password to encrypt it before it gets stored?

Thank you!

Comment: Btw hashing isn't the same as encryption. Don't mix up your terminology. Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted. In PHP this is done using password_hash(), as you correctly pointed out

Comment: Anyway, if you want to hash the password it would need to be done in the code of options.php where it handles this form being submitted.

Comment: Hi! options.php is a WordPress core file. I cannot modify it. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Well then you're out of luck. That's where the form gets posted to, so that's where it has to be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great article which goes into a lot of detail how to encrypt and decrypt a password in this situation. https://felix-arntz.me/blog/storing-confidential-data-in-wordpress/

The file options.php saves the options value/s to the database. There is no hook here which we can use to modify the value. However, the `update_option` function contains hooks which you can use to modify any value before it is saved to the database. Specifically, using the `pre_update_option_{$option}` hook, you can encrypt the password using the method in the linked article.

**Note** that you'll have to decrypt the value—again, using the method referenced in the linked article—when reading the value back out of the database.